Can we log flight time or PIC time together?
My friend rented a plane, and we ended up flying together while teaching each other. Both my friend and I are CFIs; can we log flight hours or PIC time together?

Hi. I'm guessing this is a speculative scenario, as I certainly hope that if this actually happened, at least one of the two CFIs would know the answer?

Although we shouldn't ever stop learning, I think it would be a stretch to call two CFIs flying together "teaching" under part 61 if what you are really trying to do is build time while chatting about personal techniques...

It's allowed, provided the pilot not flying is providing instruction to the pilot flying and the pilot flying is sole manipulator of the controls. The sole manipulator can log PIC time under 61.51(e)(1)(i) and the pilot providing instruction can log PIC time under 61.51(e)(3). The training needs to be properly logged in accordance with 61.51(h) and 61.189.

Can the training be ad hoc, or does it have to follow a predetermined plan?
